# Как удалить каждый N-ый элемент из списка?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Например, для `N=3` (удаление каждого третьего) как из:

```
input_ = L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

получить:

```
result = L = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Удаление, заменой ненужного среза списка на пустой, не работает:

```
>>> L[N-1::N] = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 3
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python: building new list from existing by dropping every n-th element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16406772/4279)

Comment: понял, что не так. только увидев автора вопроса/комментария/ответа :)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406772/python-building-new-list-from-existing-by-dropping-every-n-th-element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`del`-конструкция позволяет использовать срезы:

```
del L[N-1::N]
```

В общем случае, с более сложным критерием для удаления, можно создать новый список, который содержит только те элементы, которые следует сохранить, и заменить им содержимое исходного списка:

```
L[:] = [x for i, x in enumerate(L, start=1) if i % N]
```

Comment: `del L[N-1::N]` - интересный вариант, не знал об этом