# Удаление символов из строки, индексы которых кратны 3-ем

Tags: python, строки

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые программисты. 
Есть строка, нужно удалить из нее символы, индексы которых кратны 3-ем.
Укорачивать код позже буду, сейчас главное код написать. На входе должно быть input(), я просто для удобство сам ставил строки из тестов.

```
a = 'Python'
b = a[::3] # Новая строка строка с символами, чьи индексы кратны 3-ем.
c = '' # Пустая строка, куда я хотел собрать результат.
```

Попробовал простейшее

```
for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        c += i
```

Со строкой 'Python' все нормально, но вот если там будет 'Hello', то условие для второго символа l уже не выполняется. Я пробовал через b.count(i) тоже.
Я понимаю, что задачка очень простая, но я в замешательстве.

Comment: Копировать в новую строку символ из исходной, если его индекс не кратен трем - не вариант?

Comment: я так и не понял этого. Сделал так: b = list(a) del b[::3] print(''.join(b))

Comment: но я так и не понял...

Comment: Оператор % вам в помощь. И доступ к элементам строки по индексу.

Comment: Похоже, я не  знаю этот метод. Спасибо Вам. Я обязательно попрактикуюсь.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Как удалить каждый N-ый элемент из списка?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587235/23044)

Comment: Посмотрел. Спасибо. Честно сказать, я не знал про инструкцию del, когда задавал тут вопрос. Начал снова читать справочники по спискам, и нашел ее.

Answer (score 3):

В итоге вот мое решение:

```
a = input()
b = list(a)
del b[::3]
print(''.join(b))
```

А вот решение разработчиков:

```
s = input()
t = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        t = t + s[i]
print(t)
```

Comment: Что значит "решение разработчиков"? Так не следует на Питоне писать. Если вы откуда-то код берёте, то ссылки явные приведите и для первого и второго примеров.

Comment: это задачник. После успешного решения задачи становятся доступны решения других учеников и также, скажем так, эталонное решение, от авторов задачника. Первое решение - мое. Ссылка на саму задачу: http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/str/problems/delete_every_third_char/   решение от разработчиков будет видно после решения задачи. Вообще, по плану учебника, я еще не должен знать списки. Но так как Питон я учу уже некоторое время, решил через список.

Comment: Очевидным для человека, знакомого с Питоном,  решением является `s = ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i % 3])`. Вариант с `del` также достаточно читаем. Вариант `t = t + s[i]` не стоит использовать вне особых обстоятельств

Comment: когда позволяет ситуация, все операции со строками ("изменение" и так далее) я стараюсь проводить через списки и генераторы списков. На мой взгляд, так гораздо удобнее. Задачник весьма неплох этот, но видимо решения разработчики дают исходя из навыков учеников. Хотя опять же, данное решение достаточно длинное и сложное.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение

```
s = str(input())
p = str('')
i = 0
while i != len(s):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        p = p + s[i]
    i = i + 1
print(p)
```