# В питоне повторяющиеся символы считаются за один. Почему?

Tags: python

Только начинаю изучать питон, и недавно, проходя задания, обнаружил нечто, мне непонятное

Задание было таково: "Дана строка. Удалите из нее все символы, чьи индексы делятся на 3."
Недолго думая, решил написать такой код:

```
a = input()
for i in range(0, len(a) - len(a) // 3, 2):
    a = a.replace(a[i], '')
print(a)
```

Но оказалось, *что если ввести в консоль слово "hello", программа вместо "elo" выводит "eo", будто игнорируя то, что там две, а не одна "l"*. Если подставить *любое другое слово без повторяющихся символов*, программа даст правильный результат, но если вы введёте слово с повторяющимися символами, будьте готовы к неверному результату (можете сами протестировать).

Мне **неинтересно** решение моей задачи, потому что я уже нашёл альтернативу. **Мне интересно, почему так происходит**.

Comment: Всё работает так, как должно. Почитайте, как работает `str.replace`.

Comment: Вы говорите питону: удали из строки 'l'. Как, по-вашему, он вообще может понять, что вы имели в виду только один конкретный символ 'l'? Он делает именно то, что вы ему сказали - удаляет из строки 'l'. Сколько находит, столько и удаляет.

Comment: @Xander возможно ход мыслей был такой, что если указывать не символ, а элемент а[i], то только этот элемент и заменится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Штука в том, что replace удаляет/заменяет все указанные в аргументе символы. Ну вот например:

```
s = 'hello'
s2 = s.replace('l', '*')
print(s2)
```

> `he**o`

Вашу же задачу можно решить [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600452/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B-3-%D0%B5%D0%BC).