# Удаление элементов списка через срез

Tags: python, python-3.x

Удаляю элементы путем присвоения срезу пустого списка. Все работает. Но стоит задать шаг среза и выскакивает ошибка. В чем дело?

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> a[0:3] = []
>>> a
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

>>> a[0:4:2] = []
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 2
```

Comment: А зачем удалять таким образом?

Comment: Почему не использовать `del a[0:3];`, `del a[0:4:2]`?

Comment: @YozhEzhi, по-моему стОит оформить ваш коментарий как ответ...

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как удалить каждый N-ый элемент из списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587235/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать инструкцию [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement):

```
>>> a = [-1, 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> del a[0]
>>> a
[1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
>>> del a[2:4]
>>> a
[1, 66.25, 1234.5]
>>> del a[:]
>>> a
[]
```

Comment: Я знаю разные способы удаления элементов списка, спасибо.))
Вопрос был в другом. Почему не работает вторая конструкция?

Comment: @bitt-boy, почитайте [здесь](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Comment: спасибо, понятно теперь, что это не баг, а фича)

Answer (score 5):

Данная конструкция не работает, потому что вы берёте срез и на его место хотите поместить **пустой список**, а пайтон ждёт от вас **список размерности среза**. Об этом вам сообщает ошибка: `ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 0 to extended slice of size 2`

```
a[0:4:2] = [[], []]
# [[], 2, [], 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
a[::2] = [[], [], [], []]
# [[], 2, [], 4, [], 6, [], 8]]
```

Почему запись вида `a = []` то есть запись без применения шага не выдаёт ошибок?

Дело в том, что в данном случае после `=` мы указываем новую ссылку для массива - `[]`. То есть **ссылку на пустой массив**. И делая такую запись, мы просто **заменяем ссылку** у переменной `a` с **текущего непустого массива на пустой**. А срез `[start:end:step]` - это **массив ссылок на элементы массива**, и для того **чтобы заменить ссылки** в нём на какие-либо другие, то нам, естественно, **нужен массив такой же размерности**, как и срез.

```
a[::2] = [None for x in range(len(a[::2]))]
# [None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8]
```

Comment: почему тогда без шага все работает?

Comment: @bitt-boy потому что без шага вы просто изменяете ссылку у переменной, а с шагом нужно изменять ссылки на элементы массива

Comment: Непонятно, как срез a[2:4] при присвоении пустого массива заменяет ссылку у переменной a.

Comment: @bitt-boy просто эта операция `a[2:4] = []` эквивалентна операции удаления `del a[2:4]`, а эта `a[::2] = []` - нет. Считайте это особенностью языка и помните про его правила, особенно про главное: **Явное лучше, чем неявное**. И удаляйте элементы через операцию `del`, а не так, как вы делаете в этом вопросе.

Comment: а почему тогда операция a[2:4:2] = [] не эквивалентна del a[2:4:2]?

Comment: вот я и говрю, что это фича))
Спасибо за дискуссию.

Answer (score 0):

Автор задал прекрасный вопрос на понимания механизмов реализации срезов в  Пайтон -" а почему тогда операция a[2:4:2] = [ ] не эквивалентна del a[2:4:2]? "
А какой результат вернет операция a[2:4:2] = [None] и почему ?

Вот такая запись "... = А[2:4:2]" возвращает ссылку на элемент А[3]. Вот такая запись -"...del a[2:4:2]", перед выполнением оператора "del",  тоже вернет ссылку на элемент А[3]. Потому что, все, что расположено справа от оператора "=" - возвращает ССЫЛКИ НА ОБЪЕКТЫ. А все, что расположено слева от оператора "=" - возвращает не ссылки, но МЕСТО (Область) РАЗМЕЩЕНИЯ ссылок (их еще именами переменных называют).

Запись "А[2:4] = ..." эквивалентна записи "А[2:4:1] = ..." и определяет область, куда будет записана ссылка на объект, расположенный справа оператора "=". Для односвязных областей (таких как А[2:4] и А[2:4:1]  - когда все элементы среза ближайшие соседи) внутренний механизм Итератора не запускается и область готова принять ссылку на произвольный объект класса СПИСОК (список с любым количеством итерируемых элементов), и, даже, не итерируемый список вида [ ] ( [ ] = [Nan], значение NaN не имеет ссылки, в отличие от значения None) .

Многосвязные  области вида А[2:7:2], где элементы среза не ближайшие соседи, запускают механизм внутреннего Итератора, и справа от "=" для области "А[2:7:2] = ..." необходимо поставить в соответствие итерируемый объект класса Список с тремя элементами для итерирования (реализуется механизм обычного множественного присваивания). Далее все очевидно.

Перефразируя выражение из одного культового фильма - "Итераторы - они повсюду!, Ну, или почти."

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, структурируйте ваш ответ, нажав [edit]