# Удаление нескольких элементов из списка

Tags: python, list

Мне из списка необходимо удалить 0 и 2 элементы: `{usd},{rur}`.

Каким самым простым способом можно это сделать?

Менять местами я не могу, но я задал список - запрос API. Перечисление индексов через запятую в команде `del` или `remove` не работают. Через двоеточие - не вариант, потому что они не по порядку.

Я записал так:

```
balances = [{usd},{eur},{rur},{gbp}]
del (balances[0], balances[1])
```

Получается, что я два раза обращаюсь к спискам, т.е. к API. Это замедляет работу программы, так ведь?

Comment: А что мешает просто создать новый список с нужными значениями?
`balances = [balances[1], balances[3]`

Comment: В balances на самом деле элементов больше 4

Comment: Но вы точно знаете позиции элементов которые нужно удалить так?

Comment: Так точно......

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал так:

```
In [58]: balances = [{'usd'},{'eur'},{'rur'},{'gbp'}]

In [59]: del_idx = {0,2}

In [60]: balances[:] = [x for i,x in enumerate(balances) if i not in del_idx]

In [61]: balances
Out[61]: [{'eur'}, {'gbp'}]
```

Comment: `set([0,2])` -> `{0, 2}` ?

Comment: @gil9red, ага, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 1):

Что касается множественного удаления. У вас есть исходный список, а так же вы знаете позиции элементов этого списка которые нужно удалить.
Решение "в лоб".

```
array = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]
# Создаем список ненужных значений
unnecessary_values = [a[0], a[2]]

for value in unnecessary_values:
    # Проходим по списку и удаляем.
    array.remove(value)
```

Что касается ответа на второй вопрос, все зависит от реализации API, скорее всего вы просто передаете результаты работы функции в список. Список с результатами находится в памяти компьютера и не выполняет запросов к API.

Answer (score 0):

Для первых двух элементов, достаточно `del balances[:2]`:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> del L[:2]
>>> L
[3]
```

Связанный вопрос [Как удалить каждый N-ый элемент из списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587235/23044)

Если элементы для удаления не подряд идут, чтобы удалить элементы с индексами из `indices_to_remove` коллекции:

```
for i in indices_to_remove:
    del L[i]
```

Каждый `del` это `O(len(L))` операция, поэтому если количество элементов, которые вы хотите удалить пропорционально длине списка, то можно listcomp (списковое включение) использовать:

```
L[:] = [x for i, x in enumerate(L) if i in indices_to_remove]
```

Это создаёт новый список и заменяет все элементы в исходном списке. Для быстрого поиска можно `set` тип для `indices_to_remove` коллекции использовать.

Если вы хотите по значению удалить элементы:

```
L[:] = [x for x in L if x == value_to_delete]
```

Подробнее, см. в [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044).