# Как в Python заслайсить лист, чтобы он заслайсился по всем ссылкам?

Tags: python, список

У меня есть несколько объектов со ссылкой на один и тот же лист, мне нужно изменять лист в одном объекте так, чтобы он изменился во всех остальных, при чем это изменение таково, что мне нужно выкинуть из листа определенное количество элементов, очевидный способ list = list[start:end], но тогда создается новый лист и по ссылкам в объектах лист не изменяется. Есть ли способ заслайсить лист так, чтобы он изменился везде?

Answer (score 1):

"тот же лист" означает "тот же объект". Поэтому "изменять лист в одном объекте так, чтобы он изменился во всех остальных" смысла не имеет. Вы вероятно имели в виду, что у вас есть несколько *имён*, которые привязаны к одному и тому же объекту (списку).

`L = L[i:j]` не изменяет список. `L =` привязывает `L` имя к новому объекту (списку, созданному срезом).

Чтобы удалить срез:

```
del L[i:j]
```

См. [Как удалить каждый N-ый элемент из списка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587235/23044)

Естественно изменения будут видны, когда к списку и под другими именами вы будете обращаться (один объект).